# Does Google provide a supported Java API client for cloud Compute service?

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, google-api-java-client

When looking for Google a Cloud Compute Java client there are mainly two official projects.

The first one, [Google API Java client](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client#maintenance) reports that's in maintenance mode.

It suggests to use a second one, [GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java). But when checking the [Compute](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-compute) subproject, it says:

```
Note: This client is no longer receiving updates; new features in the Compute API will not be added to this client. Check https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries for the recommended Java client library to use for accessing Compute.
```

And the link provided list some third parties libraries and the first client in this post.

Do I must conclude that Google does not provide any supported Java client for cloud Compute service?

Comment: Questions about off site resources are off topic here.

Comment: This is the official one: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/compute/v1

Answer (score 0):

Google API Java client is supported and very robust. Though we aren't adding new features per se we want to get bug reports and PRs and get the client library in the best shape possible. Because all the derived services  are autogenerated, other libraries are going to be more idiomatic especially for newer APIs.

The best place for questions are here with the google-api-java-client tag or the mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-api-java-client . As the Github repo's issue count comes down I will be spending more of my time answering questions here on SO.